# singularize table name when create EDMX file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I have a database table like `ApplicationName_T_Attachments` once I generate edmx its create table class as `ApplicationName_T_Attachments`. but I want to create a table as `ApplicationName_T_Attachment`. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

While creating your model designer **please check this option Pluralize or singularize generated object names**(see in picture). If you will hover your mouse over this line and check box it will show you **"makes name in the model more descriptive and accurate by ensuring that Entity type names are singular"** means this will automatically singularize all your table class name.

[image: Please check this in picture]